# Orders on 2 sheets and new order confirmation change followup

Tags: excel, report, match, vlookup

How can I check whether order confirmations has changed from last weeks report?

I get an weekly report with orders (order number:x123) and confirmations(dates) and they are on different sheets.

What I would like to do is: With Vlookup, Find the corresponding order and print out word "old order" and then use this value to check the confirmations dates match per last week and print out "match" or " do not match".

I thought this was simple but I cant get it to work. Please help!

Comment: I use Excel 365.

Comment: That have been a autocorrect.

Comment: I solved it whit manual work and IF and vlookup commands but it is not how it should be done. (this was alot of work.)

Comment: I first added an column and vlookuped the dates from the other sheet and added a other column to do a IF = comparison to i got the information if it has been changed. Please help to get me an elegant sollution.